# Spring @Transactional rollback vs commit

Tags: java, spring, transactions, eclipselink

I have a piece of code which checks some constraints and just in case it throws an Exception. I want to log that exception as well in my syslog-db-table. The code looks like:

```
@Service    
class foo{
....
@Autowired
Syslog syslog;
...
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void saveEntity() throws Exception {
....
if (checkFails()) {
  syslog.addEntry('failure');
  throw new Exception(Reasons);
 ....
```

and the Syslog looks like

```
@Component    
class syslog{

@Autowired 
SyslogRepro syslogRepro

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void addEntry(String text){
   syslogRepro.save(text);
}
```

and the Spring interface to save data:

```
public interface SyslogRepro extends JpaRepository<SysLogEntry, Integer> {
```

My problem: As soon as an exception is thrown a rollback is started - which is in general terms fine. But I do not want to rollback my `Syslog` entries. These should be written anyway. The `propagation`-level does not help. Any other hints/helps?

Comment: Try to use `@Service` in your `syslog` and `foo` classes if you don't have it. It seems strange that your code doesn't work as expected because `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` usually works.

Comment: Updated the code. Do you have an idea what the Note for ` Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` means? Do I have to implement something for Eclipselink? `Actual transaction suspension will not work out-of-the-box on all transaction managers. This in particular applies to org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager, which requires the javax.transaction.TransactionManager to be made available it to it (which is server-specific in standard Java EE).`

Comment: Are you using `JtaTransactionManager`? (If you don't know, then probably not). Like @MikitaHerasiutsin said, `REQUIRES_NEW` is supposed to guarantee a separate transaction that isn't affected by the outer transaction's commits or rollbacks. Double check and then triple check your code before you start to search for the reason in EclipseLink or similar. Also, copy-paste your code, don't rewrite it (`Syslog` vs. `syslog`), otherwise you're bound to make mistakes there too.

Comment: uuuuhhhhh... as @Kayaman mentioned `Double check and then triple check your code` - after granting that it should work in principal I followed that advice and this really worked out as correct. I made the annotation not on the `public` method but on the nested method - which ignores the setting. Setting it on the correct method results in a working code. Thx to both of you for review and assuring that it works. You saved my day.